# Finding the smallest integer pair such that 123x+321y=1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I find the smallest integer pair $(x,y)$ such that $123x+321y=1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT;
Using [Linear congruence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem) [(Proof)](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence)

as the greatest common divisor $\textrm{gcd}(123,321)=3$ does not divide $1,$ there is no solution

Comment: can you explain why it doesn't have a solution when (123,321)=3?

Comment: @JongSui, $3(41x+107y)=1$ the LHS is divisible by $3$ unlike RHS or $$\frac13=41x+107y$$ which is an integer

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4):

Both $123$ and $321$ are multiples of 3, so their sum is $= 0 \pmod 3$ for integers $x$ and $y$, so the sum cannot equal $1 \pmod 3$.